# Access to different directories

Tags: 12.04, directory, chmod

I have recently moved to Ubuntu 12.04 and noticed that in some directories I can't even create a  directory or file (e.g:`/var/lib`). I know about the command `chmod`, but is it appropriate to use it in order to modify the access to these sort of directories?

For example I wanted to install something from the command line but gave me an error because it didn't have access and I thought that for security reasons I shouldn't change it.

Comment: Thank you !That worked !So modifying the access mode is wrong as I thought ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include what you are trying to do. Why are you needing access to those directories to install something?

Comment: I added answer to your question.

Comment: You have to be root (`sudo <command>`) use r in order to change/modify in filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No,** you shouldn't mess with those directories: *there's a good reason why you cannot modify them by default.*

You use the *Ubuntu Software Center* or the command `apt-get` (in a terminal) to install new software on Ubuntu. While you have not learned the basics of Linux, it's not recommended you modify these directories by hand.

For example, to install the Chromium browser via the terminal you run:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Or graphically,

1. Open the Dash (tapping the Windows/Super key)
2. Type `software center` and select *Ubuntu Software Center*
3. Search for `chromium web browser` on the software center
4. Install the search result (you can read a description of the app, too).